# How to get xpath for notifications that disappear within few seconds?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

**How To get error message:- authentication error with Transaction contact your help desk**

**Here is My Copy Element :**

```
<div class="alert alert-error dismissible" 
role="alert" 
data-rendered="true" 
style="overflow: hidden; height: 5.74723px; 
padding-top: 1.43681px; margin-top: 0px; 
padding-bottom: 1.43681px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;"><button class="icon-dismiss" aria-label="Dismiss" type="button"></button>
<p><strong>Error:&nbsp;</strong>authentication error with Transaction contact your help desk</p></div>
```

**I want the xpath**

Comment: it's not a good thing to demand the solution here, saw us your solutions and saw us why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get error message `authentication error with Transaction contact your help desk` you can use the following code block :

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-error dismissible']//p")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] my_text = text.split("(?=authentication)");
System.out.println(my_text[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks For your Code It's Working.

Answer (score 0):

Below Xpath working fine in chrome browser

```
 //div/p/text()
```